# Group_by and summarize is causing issues with "Run App" and app deployment

Tags: r, shiny, group-by, tidyverse

I created a small reprex below that illustrates the issue I'm dealing with using Shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights_reprex <- flights %>%
    mutate_if(sapply(flights, is.character), as.factor) %>%
    mutate(time_hour = as_date(time_hour))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("NYC Flights Reprex"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("origin_loc", label = "choose an origin location",
                               choices = unique(flights_reprex$origin),
                               selected = unique(flights_reprex$origin)),
            dateRangeInput("date_range", "select date range",
                           start = "2013-01-01", end = "2013-12-31",
                           min = "2013-01-01", max = "2013-12-31", format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
            
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotlyOutput("plot1"),
           plotlyOutput("plot2"),
           dataTableOutput("flight")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    data_reac <- reactive({
        flights_reprex %>%
            filter(., between(time_hour, input$date_range[1], input$date_range[2]), origin %in% input$origin_loc)
    })
    
    output$flight <- renderDataTable({
        data_reac()
    })
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
        flights_reprex %>%
            filter(., between(time_hour, input$date_range[1], input$date_range[2]), origin %in% input$origin_loc) %>%
            group_by(origin, time_hour) %>%
            summarize(total_dep_delay = sum(dep_delay)) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            plot_ly(x = ~time_hour, y= ~total_dep_delay) %>%
            add_lines(color = ~origin)
    })
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
        flights_reprex %>%
            filter(., between(time_hour, input$date_range[1], input$date_range[2]), origin %in% input$origin_loc) %>%
            group_by(origin, carrier) %>%
            summarize(total_arr_delay = sum(arr_delay)) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            distinct(.) %>%
            plot_ly(x = ~carrier, y = ~total_arr_delay, color = ~origin, type = "bar")
            
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

runApp()
```

When I select the whole code and press CTRL + Enter, the app is displayed without any issue, however when I click the "Run App" button there's an almost endless loop in the console displaying this message with another variable name from my dataset but the problem is the same nonetheless.

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'origin'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

When the loop eventually ends, there's a message about C packages not being big enough to support it. Now I know that touching C packages is a big No No, so I'm basically stuck. Because of this I cannot share my app either.

I'm almost sure that it's my group_by and summarize functions that are causing issues, but it's hard for me to pinpoint what exactly is going wrong.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: Since you say that it works fine with `<CTRL> + <Enter>`, I'd guess there is something missing in your code when you run the app. Guessing you use RStudio, have you tried to clean your workspace and rerun the app with `<CTRL> + <Enter>` to make sure it *really* work ?

Comment: This sounds like you have infinite recursion happening. Maybe you're calling a function from inside of itself somehow, or you've accidentally kept something in the global env that shouldn't be there. I'd try restarting R and see if that helps

Comment: I restarted R and moved the `group_by` function somewhere else in the pipe but the problem still persists,

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarize()`

Comment: That's the function I'm using

Comment: I get no issues when I specify which package summarize is coming from.

Comment: Same issue when using `dplyr::summarize` on my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, drop the `runApp()` at the bottom of the code.

When you click Run App, it sources the file, which in turn executes `runApp()`. This in turn sources the file which in turn executes `runApp()`. So on and so on.

When you run interactively with `<CTRL> + <Enter>`, the app actually launches when it gets to the `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` line. This function returns as Shiny app object. When running interactively, it prints and it's print method actually launches the app, pausing the code execution. When you close the app, the rest of the script continues but you've already closed the view so you don't see it. When clicking "Run App", the file is sourced without echo and therefore the `shinyApp` object isn't printed and only the `runApp` loop starts because it's looking for your file to produce the `shinyApp` object, not a call to run the app.

When running interactively, you actually are stopping the R execution before it gets in the loop. Without the pause from the print of the app object when using the "Run App" button, you immediately drop into the loop.

Change the end of your code to add a message and you can see:

```
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

message("Time to run the app. Yep, yep, yep")

runApp()
```

Using `<CTRL> + <Enter>` you should the app launch, but the message not displayed in the console. When you close the app, you'll see the message. When you click 'Run App' you'll see the message continuously print.

Comment: Yes, that does it! the app runs and I can share it on shinyapps.io, there's one plot that's not rendering but that's another issue! thank you very much!!!